# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{3^n n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Good evening! I've been having some - okay, a lot - of trouble with the question below:

Find the radius of convergence for $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{3^n n^2}$$

I tried using the ratio test and ended up calculating and simplifying to:

$$\dfrac{\frac{x}{3(n+1)^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Did I miss any steps, or am I good to go from here? I honestly don't know how to proceed from this point. Would really love some help!

Comment: Did you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{3^nn^2}?$$

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the ratio test then you want to take a limit of what you have (with absolute values).

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg|\frac{xn^{2}}{3(n+1)^{2}}\bigg|=|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{3(n+1)^2}=\frac{|x|}{3}
$$

The last limit can be done using L'Hopital for example.

Now the ratio test says we have convergence if $|x|/3<1$ and divergence if $|x|/3>1$. In other words convergence at $|x|<3$ and divergence at $|x|>3$.

Thus the radius of convergence is 3.